# "Learn more" link on tag suggestions fails if there's only one suggestion

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-autocomplete

While providing the tags to this very question, I get 5 tag suggestions after typing "bug". When I click on "learn more", the info page of the respective tag opens in a new tab. This is good. Now, after typing "tag-sel" I only get 1 suggestion, namely "tag-selector". When I click "learn more", the tag "tag-selector" is selected and **no info page is opened**.

I've tested this for a few tags, and this buggy behaviour seems to appear whenever there's only 1 tag suggestion. (Test it yourself at the edit link for this very question!)

Comment: GOOD WORK!  I encountered this a few times and couldn't reproduce it reliably, I just assumed it was a temporary issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what I get for wanting to use as much of the browser's native behavior as possible instead of also reinventing the fourth wheel: Stuff breaks :)

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what native behavior were you trying to use? And what wheel did you have to re-invent to fix this?

Comment: @CodyGray: Well, we *did* reinvent the textbox :) This was an issue with click events vs. focus events (where the native behavior I reffered to was using tabbing around to change focus)